# Convert a text file from ansi to UTF-8 in windows batch scripting

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, utf-8, ansi

We have a text file which is in default ANSI format and that needs to be converted into UTF-8 format. Is there any way we can use the general windows DOS commands to convert the file? We can use the PowerShell but only this command line has to be run from a different batch process.

Answer (score 5):

The PowerShell syntax is rather straightforward. This command opens a file in the default encoding and saves it as UTF-8 with BOM:

```
Get-Content <SrcFile.txt> -Encoding Oem | Out-File <DestFile.txt> -Encoding utf8
```

[The `Encoding` parameter accepts the following](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.filesystemcmdletproviderencoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0): `Ascii, BigEndianUnicode, BigEndianUTF32, Byte, Default, Oem, String, Unicode, Unknown, UTF32, UTF7, UTF8`

Answer (score 1):

Get-Content might be not optimal as it handles the input file line by line (at least, by default, if you don't use the `Raw` switch as described later), and may cause changing the line ending (for example, if you move text files between Unix and Windows systems). I had serious problems in a script just because that, and it took about an hour to find the exact reason. See more about that in [this post](https://powershell.org/2013/10/21/why-get-content-aint-yer-friend/). Due to this behavior, Get-Content is not the best choice as well, if performance matters.

Instead of this, you can use PowerShell in combination of the .NET classes (as long you have a version of the .NET Framework installed on your system):

```
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($infile) 
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outfile, $false, [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)

$sw.Write($sr.ReadToEnd())

$sw.Close()
$sr.Close() 
$sw.Dispose()
$sr.Dispose()
```

Or even more simply, use the `Raw` switch as described [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/06/15/powertip-read-text-file-in-raw-mode-with-powershell/) to avoid that overhead and read the text in a single block:

```
Get-Content $inFile -Raw
```

Comment: You've initialized your StreamsReader and StreamWriter with wrong encoding.